# WebJob is not seeing AzureWebJobsDashboard setting

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

When I click to see the logs for my WebJob on Azure, I'm seeing the following.
[image]

However, I do have the correct settings in App.config file. I checked it several times. And they're pointing to my Azure Storage account.

[image]

Any idea what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the error comes up sometimes even though it is configured in Web.config and everything is actually logged correctly.

You can add the Storage connection strings in the Web App's Application Settings. Go to the Connection strings section there and add them with type *Custom*. That should remove the error.